# jQuery ajax is not working from view file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am start working on express nodejs and stuck in ajax call or jquery from hbs view.

Here is my controller methods:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("home get request");
    res.render('index', { layout:'/layout/default' });  
});

router.post('/getPosts', function(req, res) {
    console.log("hi");
    var html = "";
    conn.query("CALL getPosts(?)",[req.session.user_id], function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(rows) {
                for (var i in rows[0]) {
                    if(i.post_text != null && i.post_image != null) {
                        html = html + '<div class="post"><div class="user"><span>'+i.user_name+'</span></div><div class="post_text"><pre>'+i.post_text+'</pre></div><div class="post_image"><img src="/images.post_images/'+i.post_image+'" /></div><div class="create_time"><span>'+i.created_on+'</span></div></div>';
                    } else if(i.post_text == null) {
                        html = html + '<div class="post"><div class="user"><span>'+i.user_name+'</span></div><div class="post_image"><img src="/images.post_images/'+i.post_image+'" /></div><div class="create_time"><span>'+i.created_on+'</span></div></div>';
                    } else if(i.post_image == null) {
                        html = html + '<div class="post"><div class="user"><span>'+i.user_name+'</span></div><div class="post_text"><pre>'+i.post_text+'</pre></div><div class="create_time"><span>'+i.created_on+'</span></div></div>';
                    }

                }
                console.log(html);
                res.json(html);
                res.send(html);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and below is my hbs file index.hbs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn add">Create Post</button></div>
    <div class="container posts_div">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('load', function(){
            $.post('/home/getPosts',{test:"jeevan"},function(res){
                console.log(res);
                $(".posts_div").html(res);
            },'json');
        });

        $(".add").click(function(){
            alert("thats working");
        });
    });

<script>
```

And my routing is

```
app.use('/home', index);
```

I want when I render the index view the ajax call fetch all posts from database and show in that view file. and one more thing is the get request on index page is coming after login when user login I redirect that user to this url and one get request is goes in index controller and view render on screen but i don't know why jquery is not working here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you include jquery ?

Comment: i keep jquery in my public folder and use static path.. jquery is loading i can see it on source in debugging @TGrif

Comment: Are you getting any of the console logs?

Comment: I am getting "home get request" only that is from when every get request come on index page but after that nothing @jlogan

Comment: ```$.post('/getPosts'...``` .... I think?

Comment: No I am not getting any console from this post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a confusion between `document` and `window`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // document is now ready
  $(document).on('load', function() {
    // doesn't work
  })
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    // window is now fully loaded
  });
});
```

[Documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for jquery `$(document).ready`

Comment: thanks @TGrif it's very silly mistake. this is right answer